# How to call function through its address in C

Tags: c, pointers

I need to call function (calloc), but I have to call it through memory address of this function stored in DWORD. The function has two int parameters. Calloc should return pointer, I think. I tried something like this

```
//global var
DWORD addressOfFunction; 
typedef void(*originalAddress)(int, int);

int main(){
originalAddress tmp = (void *)addressOfFunction;
    tmp(x, y);
}
```

Could someone explain me, where I made mistake? My solution is not correct.

Comment: What is OS? Where is `calloc` - static/shared(so/dll), etc.?

Comment: what is `callocOriginFirstThunkAddress ` ? does it return a function pointer ?

Comment: it is windows 10. I change the code. callocOriginFirstThunkAddress should be addressOfFunction

Comment: ??? if this is a homework please include your exercise because what you ask don't make sense.

Comment: Function pointers are not guaranteed to fit in a `DWORD`. Why do you think you "have to" do it this way? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart  I need to call it by address, because the original address of calloc in DLL i changed. I have modified IAT table. So now I have only address of this function.

Comment: Note that the signature of `calloc()` is `void *calloc(size_t, size_t)`, so your `typedef` is not accurate.  How many bytes are in a `DWORD`?  How may bytes are in a 32-bit function address?  In a 64-bit function address?  It is unlikely that your code is portable to both, therefore.

Comment: Perhaps you should become familiar with C and function pointers before trying platform-specific hackery like IAT modification.

Comment: You should include the error message, or a desctiption of the unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Your `typedef` is wrong. Better would be

```
typedef void* (*originalAddress)(int, int);
```

Your cast is wrong, too. `void*` is a data pointer, not a function pointer. Use a cast to `void* (*)(int, int)`, or even better to `originalAddress`.

Comment: @EladHazan, no, implicit conversions from pointers to data types (which `DWORD` is, I suppose) don't work. You have to convert explicitly (=cast) to a function pointer.

Comment: It seems that calloc will not called. If I tried to save something to allocated array, it will crash. I tried also somtehing like this. And there is also same problem. 
 `typedef void fadr(int, int); unsigned long callocAddress;` 
`fadr *f = (fadr*)callocAddress; f(x, y);`

Comment: @joe, this `typedef` is also wrong. The return type of `calloc` is `void*` and not `void`. And seeing this its parameters are `size_t` and not `int`.

Comment: I changed it for void* and size_t. And it still not called